# What is the best approach to deal with floating point issues when limiting the user input to 2 decimal places?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision

I am currently creating an application that allows users to input a weight and select their preferred unit, between kg and lbs. As of now, the database is written in Django and stores each user weight entry for a particular date as a string with 2 decimal points precision, such as,

```
weight_kg = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
```

The problem I am facing is loss of data when changing between units. For example if a user chooses 165 with `lbs` as the unit, I will store this in my database as `74.84`. When closing and reopening the page, it will fetch the data and attempt to restore it. Doing it, it will change `74.84kg` to `164.99lbs`. A loss of data, as we have no idea if the user chose `164.99lbs` or it was a rounding error.

I was starting to think that I made a mistake choosing to store the weights as precisely as the user inputted them (Precisely 2dp of precision in my Django field). Using numbers, the same problem will occur too,

```
let kg_to_lbs = 2.20462;
let lbs_to_kg = 0.453592;
((165 * lbs_to_kg) * kg_to_lbs) // 164.99....
```

Is their any best practices to prevent such issues?

Additional information,

1. User input is restricted to 2 decimal points, 0 to 1000 using a spinbutton.
2. The database stores the weights in `kg`, the client is responsible for converting them back to the unit used for display and converting them to `kg` before sending them to the server for storage.

Comment: If you convert numbers _and store them with limited precision_, then yes, you're almost guaranteed to get some slightly different numbers back. If you want to preserve exactly what the user entered, then you need to store exactly what the user entered.

Comment: @deceze When first designing my database I had a column "unit" that took into account the currently selected unit, but I believe that lead to issues as when graphing it, you only ever want one unit displayed so converting it was a bit of a nuisance. After you suggesting that this was the better approach, aswell as storing them as floats instead? I did not think of floating point issues at the time because I only limit the user to 2 decimal points of precision, but saying that, I should have given they have decimal points. I thought it was be good to store them all as one unit, kg and convert 1

Comment: Well, depends what your priorities are. If you want to preserve user input 100%, then this is clearly not the way to go. If that's your priority, then storing exactly what the user input and re-calculating everything from there every time would be the correct approach. If you _don't_ care about that and you want to normalise your values internally, then do that; you just need to inform the user appropriately.

Comment: *"I was starting to think that I made a mistake choosing to store the weight as strings..."* Storing them as strings may not be a mistake, but storing them with just two fractional digits probably is. But your conversion factors also look off. For instance, a quick search on kgs in pounds returns `0.4535924`, not `0.453592`, and `2.204623` (not `2.20462`) pounds in a kg. Using those factors, `((165 * lbs_to_kg) * kg_to_lbs)` is `165.00003921475803` which rounds to `165.00`. But even using those more-accurate factors, if you round the result of the conversion to kg...

Comment: ...to just two places (`74.84` instead of `74.842746`), it's still going to convert back incorrectly. At a minimum I would use the most precise conversion factors I could find and not artificially limit the precision in the DB. Other than that, as deceze said, you have to decide whether to keep the user's units. The right answer there probably varies depending on your use case.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Honestly I found those conversions from simply googling "lbs to kg" and copied the result, I figured 5 or 6dp of precision would still cause the issue, but it seems that in your examples it ended better. Are we suggesting that the better approach here was to store the exact unit the user chose and perform no conversion. If the user input 165 lbs and in my database I kept a column "weight" and a column "unit" like my original implementation, or are you saying to extend my decimal point in my database to like 10dp and get a better conversion ratio? while only rounding when displayin

Comment: @memelord23 - It's your call and probably depends on context of your problem that I don't have. But FWIW, I'd probably store what they entered in two columns, the number (as a number) and units, and perhaps a computed column in kg for uniform calculations if needed. For the number column, pick something that will retain at least as much precision as IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point (the type used by JavaScript's `number`). The number type you pick will depend on your RDBMS. SQL Server has `FLOAT` which defaults to `FLOAT(53)`, which is an IEEE-754 double. IIRC that's...

Comment: ...an SQL standard alias for `DOUBLE PRECISION` (but don't quote me on that, I don't have the SQL standard handy and I'm not primarily a DB guy and don't have deep knowledge of the standard on tap).

Comment: Using pounds for storage, with two decimal digits, but changing one conversion factor to be a reciprocal of the other instead of the typed numbers eliminates the problem up to at least 100 million kilograms.

Comment: FYI, the title is wrong because most of the errors you are encountering are not due to floating-point rounding but are due to fixed-point (fixing the storage format at two digits after the decimal point) and using too few digits for the conversion factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) Use the proper kilogram-to-pound factor. [By international agreement and definition, a pound is .453 592 37 kilogram.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_yard_and_pound)

(b) Convert pounds to kilograms properly, by dividing by the kilogram-to-pound factor, rather than by multiplying by a rounded reciprocal (particularly one rounded to only six significant digits).

(c) Store the weight in finer units. Simply using pounds as the units instead of kilograms results, with the above, in a conversion that accurately recovers inputs up to at least 10<sup>8</sup> kilograms. However, there are multiple ways this can be done, including:

- Store the weight as pounds with two digits after the decimal point, as mentioned above.
- Store the weight as kilograms with more than two digits after the decimal point.
- Store the weight as an integer number of grams (mathematically equivalent to the above).

Comment: How did you perform the calculation to know that storing pounds will accurately recover 10^8 kilograms?

Comment: @memelord23: I tried them all.

Comment: Could I see the algorithm you wrote to check it?

Comment: @memelord23: The C code is `#include <math.h>` / `#include <stdio.h>` / `#include <stdlib.h>` / `int main(void) { static const double lbs_to_kg = .45359237; for (double i = 0; i <= 1e10; ++i) { double a = i / 100.; double b = a / lbs_to_kg; b = round(100*b) / 100; double c = b * lbs_to_kg; c = round(100*c) / 100; if (a != c) { printf("%g -> %g.\n", a, c); exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); } } }`.